# qsort() - sorting an array of strings

Tags: c, sorting, qsort

Can't seem to find the answer on any question here.
Basically I have this line of code:

```
qsort(Code_Lines, number_of_lines, sizeof(char*), myCmp);
```

when `Code_Lines` is a `char**` - points to an array of `char*`s when each one contains a string OR pointing to NULL. What I want to do is to sort all of the strings alphabetically when the strings containing NULL will be at the END of the array.
Each string within the `Code_Lines` will be sorted by its 4 first characters (it's unequal in length of each string - and the first four characters are always different - mentioning a number from `0001` to `9999`), if it's NULL it will just put it in the end of the array.
The variable `number_of_lines` is containing the number of lines (code lines) that are in the array, AKA - number of elements (strings, in this case) in the array.
myCmp is my compare function and I wrote it this way:

```
int myCmp(const void* element1, const void* element2)
{
    int return_value;

    if(!element1) //element1 of them is NULL
    {
        return_value = 1;
    }
    else if(!element2) //element 2 is NULL
    {
        return_value = -1;
    }
    else
    {
        return_value = strncmp(*((char**)element1), *((char**)element2), 4);
    }

    return return_value;
}
```

Any idea what the problem might be ? The program just crashes there.
The function works when the array isn't containing NULL but fails when it does...

Comment: If you want to put `NULL` at the end, how come you say the first is less when it's `NULL` and that the first is greater when the second is `NULL`?

Comment: `element1` and `element2` are pointers to elements in the array and can never be `NULL`.

Comment: @chris My bad indeed, STILL, the code won't work - the code just won't function when there's NULL. Any idea why is this happening ? I could make my own sorting function, of course, but it wouldn't be as effective as 'qsort()' and I'm interested in the crash reason :P

Comment: @T.C. Why not ? The array contain pointer, a pointer cannot point to NULL ? :P

Comment: @user3745476, `qsort` provides a pointer to the elements being compared. Since elements being compared always exist, those pointers cannot be null. What they point to is either a null pointer or a string.

Comment: can you give example of the `main()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a `qsort` comparison function, the arguments are *pointers* to the elements of the array you provided, *not* the elements themselves. The elements being compared obviously exist, so these pointers can never by NULL by definition. What you want to check is whether a particular *element* is `NULL`, not the pointer to element:

```
int myCmp(const void* element1, const void* element2)
{
    int return_value;
    char * e1 = *(char **) element1;
    char * e2 = *(char **) element2;

    if(!e1) //element1 of them is NULL
    {
        return_value = 1;
    }
    else if(!e2) //element 2 is NULL
    {
        return_value = -1;
    }
    else
    {
        return_value = strncmp(e1, e2, 4);
    }

    return return_value;
}
```

Comment: @user3745476 There's not that many lines of code. Actually read it.

Comment: Oh, I just didn't get the difference in the IF statement, thanks a lot, it's working now and I understood :)